How to update the state data in client from server action in nextjs?
Is there a way to update my state in my client component while fetching data in server actions. The request is per batch (10). I want to return the result per batch and display it to frontend.
My client component:
"use client";
import { lighthouse } from "@/actions/actions";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home(props: any) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const onFormSubmit = async (formData: FormData) => {
    await lighthouse(formData, setData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-center items-center bg-slate-200 text-xl">
      <h1 className="text-4xl pb-10 font-extrabold">Pagespeed App</h1>
      <div className="shadow-md rounded-md flex flex-col p-10 bg-white gap-4 w-1/3 max-xl:w-2/3 ">
        <form action={onFormSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter WP Website URL"
            className="border rounded-md p-2"
            name="url"
          />
          <button className="border bg-blue-900 color text-white p-4 rounded-md text-sm font-semibold uppercase hover:bg-sky-700">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Server actions:
"use server";

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export async function lighthouse(
  formData: FormData,
  setData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<{}>>
) {
  const url = formData.get("url") as string;
  let page = 1;
  let isDone = false;

  while (!isDone) {
    console.log(isDone, page);
    let params = `?page=${page}`;
    const result = await getPages(url, params);
    const totalPages = result?.response?.headers.get(
      "x-wp-totalpages"
    ) as string;

    const scores = await pageSpeed(result?.urls);
    setData((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      scores
    }));
    revalidatePath("/");
    console.log(scores);
    if (page < parseInt(totalPages)) {
      page += 1;
    } else {
      isDone = true;
    }
  }
}

It seems that this is not allowed but what is the proper way? I want to update the frontend with results because the request are in batched.
